# Mysqli returns affected row = -1 even on successful updates

Tags: php, debugging, mysqli, phpstorm, xdebug

I am working on database CRUD functions using mysqli api.

While working on update operation with the command below:

```
$mysqliObject->query('UPDATE table_name SET some_fields WHERE some_conditions')
```

Now even if the rows are being updated successfully in my database, `$mysqliObject->affected_rows` gives value `-1`

Even if some rows(suppose 4 rows) are updated, `$mysqliObject->affected_rows` still gives `-1`

> Update

Also `$mysqliObject->info` gives this:

```
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

> Update 2

I am using **PhpStorm** as my IDE and I've enabled debug mode on.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing the `->affected_rows` directly after running the UPDATE

Comment: And `-1` should be telling you that the query failed, are you absolutely POSITIVE the query was successful?

Comment: I am using phpstorm and the ide debugger displays each properties of the object and I'm pretty sure its the `affected_rows`

Comment: Add a test after the update, to check it completed without reporting any errors

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, that's why its being confusing..

Comment: Is anyone using **PHPStorm**. 

As I performed debugging with breakpoints, it showed `$mysqliObject->affected_rows = -1` . But when breakpoints were disabled, it showed `$mysqliObject->affected_rows = 1` . 

I tested this several times and it was so for each tests.

Comment: Note your choice of IDE has nothing to do with the problem though; it doesn't have anything to do with the actual **execution** of the code.

Comment: I have performed the test many times and each time when I pause the program and perform line by line program execution, the value is -1 but when done without any pause in program, it'll give 1 when table is successfully updated. Also I found that it gives -1 on every cases when executing with breakpoints.